# Programacion dinamica, Memoizacion

Tags: python

me podrian colaborar con un ejercicio en python ?¿
Mejor dicho como puedo volver, que el siguiente codigo use memoizacion, este codigo es para calcular la descomposicion de numeros primos, pero me han pedido que le implemente memoizacion, espero me puedan apoyar, gracias.

```
b = int (input ('Ingrese un valor: '))
mylist=[]

def descomponer(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i ==0:
            mylist.append(i)
            n=n//i
            return descomponer(n)
    mylist.append(n)

    if len(mylist)>1:
      mylist.append(n)
      print(mylist)

    else:
      print ('no es un número primo')
 
descomponer(b)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Qué has intentado o investigado al respecto?

Comment: Usa una criba de Eratosthenes.

Comment: Hay un módulo de python que te ayuda en eso. No recuerdo cual era.